# Hi I need help for loops

Tags: python, loops

so i wrote code, so it will print m-(m%10), i want it to print: plus this numbers untill %10 will be 0. any help will be appreciated. sorry for bad english. my written code is down below.

```
a=int(input('X= '))
b=int(input('Y= '))
c=int(input('C= '))
d=int(input('D= '))
e=int(input('E= '))
f=int(input('F= '))
j=a+b+c+d+e+f
numbers=[a,b,c,d,e,f] 
for i in (numbers):
    if i%2==1:
            m=j-i
            print(m-(m%10))
    elif i%2==0:
            m=j
            print(m-(m%10))
```

Comment: What is your expected output, and what is your actual output? Welcome to SO, please be sure to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intent, you want print values of

```
a
a + b
a + b + c
a + b + c + d
a + b + c + d + e
a + b + c + d + e + f
```

but not always all - you want to stop when the sum is divisible by 10.

If this is what you need, here is the code:

```
a = int(input('A = '))
b = int(input('B = '))
c = int(input('C = '))
d = int(input('D = '))
e = int(input('E = '))
f = int(input('F = '))

numbers = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
sum     = 0 

for i in numbers:
    sum = sum + i
    print(sum)
    if sum % 10 == 0:
       break
```